# Destructing assignment order in Python

Tags: python

Today I came across this expression:

```
(x,_),(y,_) = load_data()
```

...and I'm wondering what is the order of assignment.

---

For example `x,x,x = 1,2,3` set `x` to `3` from my test, does it actually set `x` to 1, 2, than 3?

What's the rule it follows? And what happens in more complex conditions like the first code snippet?

Comment: expressions are evaluated from left to right. to last one wins, yes.

Comment: also, the type of ``1,2,3`` is a tuple. So it has a defined order.

Comment: You can find out what a statement does by entering it into the Python console. The rules are defined in the reference manual: https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html - it maps tuple items in the left hand side to tuple items in the right hand side, 1:1, recursively. (When not using the star operator.) In general, if an assignment statement is ambiguous, I'd recommend just writing out multiple assignments explicitly.

Comment: `import dis; dis.dis('(x,_),(y,_) = load_data()')` This makes the order very clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant part of the [documentation on assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html) is:

> If the target list is a comma-separated list of targets, or a single target in square brackets: The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets in the target list, and the items are assigned, **from left to right**, to the corresponding targets.

(Emphasis mine: that's how the order is determined.)

Answer (score 1):

It will load the couple of tuples that load_data() returns into variables x, y and _ which you define. This in turn will assign the first member of each tuple to x and y and the last value to the `_` variable (which gets overridden the second time it's called).

Example:

```
def load_data():
    return (1,2), (3,4)

(x, _), (y, _) = load_data()

print(x, y, _)
```

Outputs

> 1 3 4

Answer (score 0):

This is a really interesting question, though I should say first that you probably shouldn't assign the same variable more than once per line.

The first example expects `load_data()` to return two tuples. It will assign `(x, _)` to the first one. The underscore is a convention for unpacking values you don't care about. It will be overwritten when the second tuple is unpacked.